# TightVNC "Actively refused connection"

Tags: windows-10, ssh, tightvnc

I am trying to use TightVNC to connect to a computer at work through a SSH Tunnel. I am using PUTTY to create the tunnel. I am on a Windows 10 Home computer and trying to connect to a Windows 2008 R2 Server. I can connect using PUTTY to the SSH, but when I try and connect through VNC it gives me:

> "Error in TightVNC viewer no connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it."

I use port 2850 to create the tunnel. The tunnel is there and works fine. I can manipulate the host via command line.

I know the standard questions, and will tell you straight up when I use my Windows 10 Tablet it connects through the same process just fine. All settings are precisely mirrored on both home devices. I have been using this setup at home for sometime and this is the first time I have ran into the error.

I have looked all over the internet and couldn't find an answer that exactly meets my question. There is a lot out there that does from Windows to Linux, but not Windows to Windows Server.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I figured it out.  On this machine for some reason I needed to create the tunnel using `localhost:2850` instead of the IP address. It all works now.

Answer (score 0):

VNC servers generally refuse connections from localhost.  Your tunneled connection likely appears to originate from localhost.   The line includes a `-localhost` option to enable this.  There should be an option in the Windows control panel to set this flag for the server.

Comment: My tunnel is setup to go through "rwrchiro.ddns.net:22" and creates a tunnel on 2850. VNC then logs into "localhost:2850." I would agree that this is the problem except that it works the exact same way on all systems and they can access the connection just fine. This is specific to one system. I did however make sure it allowed  and it now I am getting "Connection has been gracefully closed"

Comment: @ChristopherCollins The localhost setting needs to be set on each server.  It is likely that on the one system it did not get set correctly, or the VNC service was not restarted after it was set.

Comment: I only remote to one server and it is set.  I have also restarted the server and service.

Comment: Don't you mean -localhost, not -localhsot ?